# How to set a minimum and maximum duration using HTML date selector

Tags: html

I am using a form in HTML which allows a user to request a piece of equipment from the website and input some details about themselves. When making the booking, I am using the input="date" for the dates so they can select the date they want the booking to start and finish. I am wanting the booking to have a minimum duration of 1 day and a maximum of 14 days. After having a look online, I am unsure of how I could do this in either HTML or PHP? Has anyone came across this before or is this even achievable in HTML? Or would it be something that PHP could do? Thank you :)

```
        <label id="text">Select Equipment:</label>
            <select name="item" id="equipment">
            <option value="Router"<?php //$ItemID = 1; ?>>Router</option>
            <option value="Switch (Layer 2)"<?php //$ItemID = 2; ?>>Switch (Layer 2)</option>
            <option value="Switch (Layer 3)"<?php //$ItemID = 5; ?>>Switch (Layer 3)</option>
            <option value="Firewall"<?php //$ItemID = 6; ?>>Firewall</option>
            <option value="Access Point"<?php //$ItemID = 9; ?>>Access Point</option>
            <option value="Serial Cable"<?php //$ItemID = 10; ?>>Serial Cable</option>
            <option value="Ethernet"<?php //$ItemID = 13; ?>>Ethernet</option>
            <option value="Server"<?php //$ItemID = 14; ?>>Server</option>
            <option value="IP Phone"<?php //$ItemID = 17; ?>>IP Phone</option>
            </select>

            <p>
                <label id="text">Full Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="user" name="user"/><br>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label id="text">Student ID:</label>
                <input type="text" id="user" name="studentid"/><br>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label id="text">Date From:</label>
                <input type="date" name="datefrom"/><br>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label id="text">Date To:</label>
                <input type="date" name="dateto"/><br>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label id="text">Address Line 1:</label>
                <input type="text" id="user" name="addressline1"/><br>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label id="text">Town:</label>
                <input type="text" id="user" name="town"/><br>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label id="text">Postcode:</label>
                <input type="text" id="user" name="postcode"/><br>
            </p>

            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Request" id="btn"/>
    <form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The date input fields do support a min and max attribute.
e.g.

```
 <input type="date" name="dateto" min="2021-05-17" max="2021-05-31" />
```

Would allow a user to submit a date only between 17th May 2021 and 31st May 2021.

I suspect the issue you're contemplating is setting the end date's maximum value relative to the start date? If so - you'd be looking at using JavaScript to be able to set this when the date-from value has been changed.

A (minimally tested) rough guide of some Vanilla Javascript that could be used:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

    var date_from = document.querySelector('#date-from');

    if(date_from) {
        date_from.addEventListener('change', function(){
          var selected_start = new Date(date_from.value);
          minDate = selected_start;
          minDate.setTime(selected_start.getTime() + 1 * 86400000); // add one day
          maxDate = selected_start;
          maxDate.setTime(selected_start.getTime() + 14 * 86400000); // add 14 days
          document.querySelector('#date-to').setAttribute('min', minDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
          document.querySelector('#date-to').setAttribute('max', maxDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
        });
    }
});
```

You would need to put the IDs #date-from and #date-to onto your date inputs, and as I say the above is a rough idea without being tested.